# Check if related data exists within aggregated data

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to write a SQL query with the ability to check if a certain data exists within the aggregated data range, i'm using `ARRAY_AGG` function for that in the query.

Here is how the schema looks like:

```
Schema Browser
----------------------------
  + post (TABLE)
      postid int4(10)
      name varchar(5)

  + posttag (TABLE)
      posttagid int4(10)
      postid int4(10)
      tagid int4(10)

  + tag (TABLE)
      tagid int4(10)
      name varchar(20)
```

Here is my query to fetch all the posts with tags using `ARRAY_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post,
LATERAL (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT tag.name ) AS tags 
    FROM tag, posttag 
    WHERE post.postid = posttag.postid
    AND posttag.tagid = tag.tagid
) posts
```

It will output this result set, that is exactly what i'm looking for:
[image]

The problem is when i try to use a tag filter! For example, i want to get all the posts that has "node" and "test" tag in it. Assuming "test" tag has id 1 and "node" tag's id is 2. So i'm trying `IN` condition like this `tag.tagid IN (1, 2)` and here is how i will add the where condition with the query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post,
LATERAL (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT tag.name ) AS tags 
    FROM tag, posttag 
    WHERE post.postid = posttag.postid
    AND posttag.tagid = tag.tagid
    AND tag.tagid IN (1, 2)
) posts
```

But now it looses all the other tags, as if all the posts has only two tags which is not true. and some null tags as well!
[image]

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b3aa/4) playground.

How I can simply check if id 1 and 2 exists within the ARRAY_AGG so that it won't change the result?

Comment: If you want a comma separated list, `string_agg()` is probably better than `array_agg()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0be4b0895edff6993a258d59e743953e)

The `WHERE` clause filters the tags before aggregating. In your case a `HAVING` clause helps which can filter the grouped records. The `&&` array operator checks for overlaps between two arrays:

```
   SELECT * FROM post,
    LATERAL (
      SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT tag.name ) AS tags 
        FROM tag, posttag 
        WHERE post.postid = posttag.postid
        AND posttag.tagid = tag.tagid
        HAVING ARRAY[1,2] && ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT tag.tagid)
    ) posts
```

Result:

```
postid | name  | tags               
-----: | :---- | :------------------
     1 | hello | {go,node,rust,test}
     2 | world | {node,test}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by joining everything together the way you want it. Instead of creating the tags list in a subquery and joining it to `post`, join `post`, `posttag`, and `tag` together and use a `GROUP BY` to create the tags list. I used `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in case a `post` didn't have a `posttag`:

```
SELECT p.postid,
  p.name,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT t.name) AS tags
FROM post p
 LEFT JOIN posttag pt
   ON p.postid = pt.postid
 LEFT JOIN tag t
   ON pt.tagid = t.tagid
GROUP BY p.postid,
  p.name
```

The above will give you the same result as your unfiltered query, and it has a much better query plan (4.2k vs 82.5k). Using `INNER JOIN` can improve that even further (3.9k).

As for filtering, the problem you were having was that you were only filtering the `posttag` and `tag` join, not the actual posts. For this, use a subquery to select from `posttag` the `postid`'s that have the desired tags. Use that in an `IN` statement like so:

```
SELECT p.postid,
  p.name,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT t.name) AS tags
FROM post p
 LEFT JOIN posttag pt
   ON p.postid = pt.postid
 LEFT JOIN tag t
   ON pt.tagid = t.tagid
WHERE p.postid IN (SELECT postid FROM posttag WHERE tagid IN (1,2))
GROUP BY p.postid,
  p.name
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b3aa/16/0)